# Magento Code Migration

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I'm trying to migrate my existing **Magento 1.9.2 code to Magento 2.2.2**
I cloned the code migration toolkit from github and followed the steps but nothing has happened after executing the migration commands.

Can someone guide me through another approach or a detailed step by step guide to get the code migration toolkit to work?

Comment: What problem occurred when you are doing this process?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh I followed the steps on the github repo of the code migration toolkit, however, after running the commands nothing has happened.. no errors were displayed even in order to debug the issue

Comment: Working or not?

Answer (score -1):

Please execute this command from your Magento root directory to migrate Magento1 to Magento2,

```
- composer update
- composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
- composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.2.2
- php bin/magento migrate:settings vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
- php bin/magento migrate:data --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.4/config.xml
- Flush all Magento 2 cache types
- Reindex all Magento 2 indexers
```

Replace 1.9.2.4 with your Magento1 version.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Jad Ashour asking for code migration tool. You have mentioned data migration tool. How will it help him or others?

Comment: Why the code migration tool is missing?