# How can i migrate website from Magento1 to Magento2 with in short time?

Tags: magento2, migration

Actually in my magento store orders are placed frequently so i only can make my site in maintenance mode for 6 to 7 hours.

My issue is there are approx 50000 orders and 30000 customers and too many products so i migrate my magento store using UBER Them Tools and it takes 2 days which are not right choice so is there any other method which are fast suitable for migration.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Data Migration Tool` you can migrate your Magento1 to Magento2 easily.

This will help you more.

[Magento Code Migration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217020/magento-code-migration/220811#220811)

If any problem occurred then inform me.